# Wrong Azerty keyboard layout for Logitech MX keys Azerty version in Linux

Tags: linux, logitech, azerty-keyboard

I have a very weird issue. I purchased the Logitech MX Keys Macintosh version. After settings up Pop OS by choosing the French Macinstosh version (which) is the correct one, the Logitech version swaps my @ and < key strokes. When I connect a native Macintosh keyboard it works. Anyone any tip how I can fix this?

Comment: I guess I'm the only one having this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue but not sure about the cause, pressing <kbd>fn</kbd> +<kbd>p</kbd> for 3 seconds seems to switch it back correctly.

Also, via the Logitech software:

> disable the 'Always keep in mac-layout'.

Comment: This does not work on Linux

Comment: @FilipVanReeth: It did work for me on Linux.

Comment: Thx for the help, it worked for me as well under Linux (NixOS)